# Dell Inspiron 17r's Wifi doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, system-installation, dell, 14.10

I had to reinstall my Ubuntu system because it was not working properly so I did with a USB installation and I kept my old /home. The Wifi was working good on my 14.10 system and even in Live CD but now I came to 14.04 LTS and isn't working at all. 
What are the packages and I need to download to have back my wifi working?

```
    lspci | grep -i wireless

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)


lspci -vv -s 02:00.0

    02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
        Region 0: Memory at f1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Comment: Did you fix this? Got same problem :shmrc:

Comment: Try it http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1795211